# How to read object name using JSONReader

Tags: android, jsonreader

I am  developing an android application and i need to parse the json data from YQL 
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%20*%20from%20%20yahoo.finance.historicaldata%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%27YHOO%27)%20and%20startDate%20%3D%20%272016-01-01%27%20and%20endDate%20%3D%20%272016-04-10%27&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=

I am using JsonReader to access the Count and the Result object. The problem am facing is how do I check the object name and then call  beginobject on results object . I am able to fetch the counts value though from the Json Feed

Comment: Please, google some tutorial to use JSON on android. There is nothing complicate about this library. If you stuck at some point, post your code and ask again.

Comment: I did debuged the code to and fro and figured out how the json is being parsed .quite a fun it was ... :)

Comment: Don't hesitate to update your question to be more specific an post the answer.